How to Set Up Teleultrasound with Single-PC Control for Dual Franka Emika Robot Arms
I am trying to set up teleultrasound with both the master system and slave system using Franka Emika robot arm. Franka Emika controller is connected to a PC with a network cable. Is there anyway that I would be able to use one PC to establish a connection to the remote robot as well? Essentially, using one computer at the master side to control both the robots?
I have read about using UDP and ROSRemote, but I wasn't too sure what is the best way to approach this. A low latency less than 1ms is required.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!
